# Relationship between Teams Messaging Extension with action command, the underlying bot and access via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to call a messaging extension (with action command) and access Graph API via a bot for getting different resources of the channel (e.g. retrieve all messages or get replies for my message).
In the examples from Microsoft it is stated as a prerequisite that I have to do the "Bot channels registration" so that the access of the bot to the Graph API via OAuth2 works.
Do I really need this channel registration? Or is there another way?

As a test, I had created a azure free trial, with which I performed the "Bot channels registration" and could also save the ID and secret for the Graph Api access in the registration. With this I had success. Now the 30 days testing period is over and I'm interested in whether it would work without.

Thanks for your help

Update:
Thats my code to initialize graph api:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(AppId)
            .WithClientSecret(AppSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant}"))
            .Build();
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage
                .Headers
                .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
return Task.FromResult(0);
        }));
```

Comment: Yes, To get the access token your bot need to registered in azure.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
In the meantime, I have changed my code so that access with the graph api partially works (see update in question)
The following call is executed successfully and also returns the expected result:

`var channels = graphServiceClient.Teams["123"].Channels.Request().GetAsync().Result;`

But the following call returns an UnknownError

`var messages = graphServiceClient.Teams["123"].Channels["456"].Messages.Request().GetAsync().Result;`

I assume this is related to the access type (delegated or application permissions).
Can someone explain why it doesn't work?

Comment: yes, it is necessary to enable required graph delegated or application permissions for respective API to get results. Could you please check on that [refer document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll check the provided link.

Comment: Unfortunately the provided link didn't help me at all.
So, when I take microsoft tutorial (https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/create-messaging-extension) in "Register your web service with the Bot Framework" it says: "If you choose to register without using an Azure subscription you will not be able to take advantage of the simplified OAuth authentication flow provided by the Bot Framework".
Does anyone have a tutorial or sample application which shows how authentication can be implemented when the bot is only registered (without Azure)?

Comment: @Anne, That's correct. For OAuth authentication, you need to register the bot with azure for sure.

Comment: Ok, so thanks for your response. I will use an azure account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For OAuth authentication, you need to register the bot with azure for sure.